# Не могу победить Clusterer в Yandex Maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть работающая карта без кластера. Стало появляться всё больше меток и решил упростить читаемость. Для этого создал кластер и заменил добавление отдельных точек к объекту карты на добавление кластера. Всё это происходит внутри  `function init()` и это её последние строки.

Собственно вот так вот всё работает:

```
...
echo "              myMap.geoObjects.add(algCollectionHome);"."\r\n";
echo "              myMap.geoObjects.add(algCollectionPoint);"."\r\n";
echo "              myMap.setBounds(algCollectionPoint.getBounds());"."\r\n";
...
```

, а  вот так вот не работает:

```
...
echo "              myMap.geoObjects.add(algCollectionHome);"."\r\n";
echo "              var myClusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer( {clusterDisableClickZoom: false} );"."\r\n";
echo "              myClusterer.add(algCollectionPoint);"."\r\n";
echo "              myMap.geoObjects.add(myClusterer);"."\r\n";
...
```

Не работает - это значит, что на карте не показываются элементы коллекции `algCollectionPoint`.

Коллекция создается так:

```
var algCollectionPoint = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(...)
```

Элементы добавляются так

```
algCollectionPoint.add(new ymaps.Placemark(...))
```

Comment: Без минимального примера сложно сказать наверняка. Но вообще коллекции могут содержать вложенные коллекции, а кластеризатор таких структур не поддерживает, потому спотыкается. В него надо передавать либо отдельные объекты, либо массив, иначе он просто не поймёт откуда координаты точек брать.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо YaCor! Истинно так - не поверил, что мог так лохануться и пошел читать API (до этого читал 3 раза ). Для особо одарённых:

> В кластеризатор можно добавить javascript-массив меток **(не
> геоколлекцию)** или одну метку.

В итоге в цикле заменил добавление в коллекцию на добавление в кластер и всё работает.

P.S. Как мне пометить вопрос решённым? Задавал его в процессе регистрации и в профиле этот вопрос моим не считается.